# Mobile Safari's sporadic behavior in opening bit.ly's which redirect to app store

Tags: ios, app-store, mobile-safari

I'm using bit.ly to link to an app via the URL structure: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id. Sometimes Safari just does a redirect. Sometimes it shows the below alert. Either way it appears that the bit.ly link isn't firing.

1. What is the reason for this sporadic behavior?
2. How do I get the bit.ly link to fire?

It doesn't seem to matter if use the alternate URL structure of: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/

[image]

Comment: I came across the same issue. Have you found a solution? Thanks